# LibGDX issue with units

Tags: libgdx, units-of-measurement

Hello I have a question for you guys about LibGDX and its units.

Firstly I've created world with Earth like gravitaion vector:

```
world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.2f);, true);
```

Next I created constant value of PPM (pixel per meter)

```
public static final float PPM = 32;
```

it basicly means that 32 pixels is one meter in Box2D world.

Then I created player body with such shape (only important lines here):

```
shape.setAsBox(16 / PPM, 40 / PPM);
fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
```

which for me means that he is 0.5m wide and a little bit more than 1m tall. I scaled all my textures so it looks ok but here's the question. To jump I have to use this:

```
playerBody.applyForceToCenter(0, 1000, true);
```

and player jumps for about 1m high. But it's 1000N! How is it possible? He should be fire to space with such high force.

edit: additionaly his jumps looks like he's on the moon or his size is huge

Comment: How do you do your step? What mass does your player body have?

Comment: 1kg per m^2 as I pasted. world.step(delta, 3, 3);